# Express server and NGINX proxy only serving index.html, no other files

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I have a very simple express app which serves everything in the build folder for my react app. Here's the entire thing:

```
const express = require("express");
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(express.static(process.env.PUBLIC_DIR));
app.use(express.json());

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}...`);
});
```

When running this on my local machine, it works fine. No issues.

On my EC2 instance, I'm using NGINX as a reverse proxy. Here's what the config in my default sites-available file looks like:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
}

location /upvotes {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:5002/;
}
```

When you just go to the main site, another express app on 5000 serves a totally unrelated Gatsby project. That works fine, no issues.

When you go to /upvotes, this express app on 5002 **does** serve the index.html file perfectly fine, but it doesn't serve any of the accompanying .js and .css files that are also in that directory.

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually gave up and combined the two express apps into one and handled the /upvotes route using express.